# MD5 of File doesnot match data in flash Error with ESP32 S3

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, espressif

I am getting the `fatal error MD5 of file not match data in flash`. Below is the output of upload.

```
[1/5] cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Users\INOMETRICS\espressif\workspace\blink\build\esp-idf\esptool_py && python D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 partition --type app D:/Users/INOMETRICS/espressif/workspace/blink/build/partition_table/partition-table.bin D:/Users/INOMETRICS/espressif/workspace/blink/build/blink.bin"
blink.bin binary size 0x31340 bytes. Smallest app partition is 0x100000 bytes. 0xcecc0 bytes (81%) free.
[2/5] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Users\INOMETRICS\espressif\workspace\blink\build\bootloader\esp-idf\esptool_py && python D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x0 D:/Users/INOMETRICS/espressif/workspace/blink/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin"
Bootloader binary size 0x5180 bytes. 0x2e80 bytes (36%) free.
[2/3] cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4\components\esptool_py && D:\Espressif\tools\cmake\3.20.3\bin\cmake.exe -D IDF_PATH="D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4" -D SERIAL_TOOL="python D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip esp32s3" -D SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS="--before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash @flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY="D:/Users/INOMETRICS/espressif/workspace/blink/build" -P D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake"
esptool.py esp32s3 -p COM8 -b 460800 --before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size 2MB 0x0 bootloader/bootloader.bin 0x10000 blink.bin 0x8000 partition_table/partition-table.bin
esptool.py v3.2-dev
Serial port COM8
Connecting...
Chip is ESP32-S3
Features: WiFi, BLE
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 70:04:1d:be:ab:74
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00000000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00041fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Compressed 20864 bytes to 13002...
Writing at 0x00000000... (100 %)
Wrote 20864 bytes (13002 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 0.1 seconds (effective 1284.4 kbit/s)...
File  md5: 1d4bc050825217f8434a2cfd167894cd
Flash md5: 1b32e380d00eb036ce18a632dedbe04d
MD5 of 0xFF is b145c0e952abec491d69c8c5f8ac47c4

A fatal error occurred: MD5 of file does not match data in flash!
CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:56 (message):
  python
  D:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py
  --chip esp32s3 failed
```

I am getting the same error while uploading with esp-idf and Arduino ide or platformio.

How could i solve the issue.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have managed to get it working now, the issue encountered was with the strapping pins. Specifically, Pin 45 of ESP32S3 is responsible for configuring VDD_SPI_FLASH. To ensure it operates at 3.3V, the pin should be connected to the ground. Otherwise, it will function at 1.8V, which might cause problems with the Flash functionality.

Fortunately, this can also be resolved by burning some EFUSES using the espefuse.py tool, which comes along with esptool.py. All you need to do is run the command: `espefuse.py set_flash_voltage <voltage>` (where voltage can be either 3.3V or 1.8V or OFF). For more details, you can visit: [link to the official documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32s3/espefuse/set-flash-voltage-cmd.html).